# Starting only a subset of all beans in an applicationcontext

Tags: java, spring

We have a setup where an ApplicationContext has a lot of beans defined, but depending on circumstances, only a subset of these beans need to be started (and by started I mean the Lifecycle callbacks and start() method).

Basically, what I'd like to do is to call "start" on a single bean, and have all the *dependencies* of that bean started in the regular bean startup order, but nothing else.

Is there any existing code for something like this? If not, what would be a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I usually split the bean configuration into separate files and just import the file that contains the necessary beans. If you can avoid circular dependencies, you can import the files into each other. For example, you could have a service.xml defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Service and lower layer beans.</description>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gamma.purple"
        use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <import resource="dao.xml" />

</beans>
```

Since `dao.xml` should have no dependencies on service.xml, if you only wanted the dao beans, you could just import that file, and no service beans would be loaded.

Comment: Thanks - separate configuration files are not an option for me right now. The idea is very clear to me, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set lazy initialization on beans, such that they're loaded when necessary. An example of a bean node from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init:

```
<bean id="lazy" class="com.foo.ExpensiveToCreateBean" lazy-init="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this is also a non-solution for me, as I need to beans *configured*, but not *started*. Lazy-init prevents configuration as well.

Comment: Okay, so what do you mean by "started?"

Comment: "and by started I mean the Lifecycle callbacks and start() method". Right from the question. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that when I first read the question. Yeah, for that you'd probably want manual insertion into the context, or use composition to initialize beans and prepare them to be inserted into objects that implement Lifecycle. Thus: the objects that contain state would be initialized eagerly, and the Lifecycle objects would have a dependency on those objects; the Lifecycle objects would be lazily initialized, and thus would start() only on reference.

Comment: Hmmh, not exactly sure what you mean. Though - *all* objects need to be initialized (configured), but only some should to be started. It is not easily possible for me to separate the parts that should be configured and the parts that require starting in to separate objects.

Comment: Well, imagine you have configuration data in objects in sets A and B, but only objects in set B should be "started." You'd have a set C that contained the configurations; A and B would have objects in set C injected, but objects in A would be set to lazy-init - that means on context load, objects in set B would be started, and objects in set C would be configured, but objects in set A would not be "started."

Answer (score 0):

You could separate out the subset of beans into a separate xml file and use it to create a new spring application context. This new context can refer to the main application context (and the beans defined within them) which is initialized during application startup.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{...}, parentContext);
// once you have finished using it, close the context
ctx.close();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about parenting application contexts. However, in your suggestion you talk about separating a subset of the beans in to separate file - however, I need all beans *configured* and present in the context, but not started.